# .NET Core Listener Kafka Topic in backstage

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Current Example in Internet about Kafka Listener always implemented in main function. I want to find a option that kafka can operation in backstage and Kafka can't influence my controller to listen HTTP Request.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Note: Backstage is a NodeJS software product, not .NET... I assume you mean background?

Answer (score 0):

> Current Example in Internet about Kafka Listener always implemented in main function

That's not a requirement. You can start a Kafka consumer in a Thread very easily and start it from any function (but will eventually have to be started from the main function)